# How to change the color of text to white only using Bootstrap no css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the text color to white without using a single line of css code is it possible to do that using any Bootstrap Class?

Comment: And why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: You do realise that Bootstrap is MOSTLY CSS don't you and that everything that Bootstrap does revolves around CSS.  This sounds something like: how do I pick my nose without using my finger?

Answer (score 13):

Use Bootstrap-v4.

```
class="text-white"
```

Reference: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/

Answer (score 2):

The classes for text colors are: .text-muted, .text-primary, .text-success, .text-info, .text-warning, and .text-danger

there is no white text color in default bootstrap classes.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<p class="text-muted">This text is muted.</p>
<p class="text-primary">This text is important.</p>
<p class="text-success">This text indicates success.</p>
<p class="text-info">This text represents some information.</p>
<p class="text-warning">This text represents a warning.</p>
<p class="text-danger">This text represents danger.</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this using font-awesome??

Comment: @Shubham no, you can create your own class for white text color. All you have to do is to put this line of code in your own css file: `.text-white { color: #FFF; }`. You can also edit bootstrap css file and add this line of code there if you host it locally, but it's not recommended to edit third party files

Comment: This is no longer true starting on Bootstrap 4
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/colors/

There's a "text-white" class now.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Font-Awesome then you can do this using a class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Colors</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<p class="icon-dark">This is for Black.</p>
<p class="icon-light">This is for White.</p>
</body>
</html>
```